# Installing QxOrm in debian ubuntu 11.10(oneric) using qt creator

Tags: c++, qt

Error while building qx orm using Qt Creator in ubuntu 11.10

Postby batosai » Mon Feb 20, 2012 11:31 am
hi i am new to Qxorm.
i was trying to build Qxorm using qt creator it is giving me following errors.
1) error: cannot find -lboost_serialization-mt
2) error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

i am using boost 1.48.0 and it is installed in the path /usr/local/include/boost
boost library path is /usr/local/lib

so please help me with the flags i have to set in qxorm.pri file and also where does the Qxorm get installed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem, except I've managed to solve the linker error by creating a symlink to (in my case)libboost_serialization.so.1.48.0 and then it worked, however the library got created in my local folder and now I don't know where to copy them and/or how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

I've read somewhere that -mt was removed form their libraries. I managed to remove it from .pro and .pri files, and used the `sudo make install` command to install it. However, when I tried to build the example project qxBlog the build failed because it didn't recognize `QxOrmd` library. In conclusion either QxORM have to step up their game or we need to create a **WORKING** ORM for Qt framework